# Difference between useSelector and useAppSelector?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I came across useAppSelector while using redux with RTK query. So what will be the difference between useSelector and useAppSelector gonna be or both works in the same way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On a runtime level, they are 100% equal. The difference is that one is untyped so the `state` variable is `unknown` and needs to be manually typed by you on every single call of `useSelector` - and you can pass in everything wrong there without causing an error.

`useAppSelector` on the other hand gets declared with your `RootState` in one place and after that it's typesafe, ready to be used everywhere in your application.

Comment: That is why useAppSelector and useAppDispatch is recommended to be used with TypeScript.

Comment: so useApp* is for typescript & useSelector/useDispatch is for plainJS?

Comment: Yes, TypeScript needs some extra information, so you have to create those custom-typed hooks.